# Substitute all 'A' with \textsc{a}

Tags: catcodes, substitution

Can I use catcode to substitute all capital letters in my document to `\textsc{\myletter}`?

EDIT: I would like to make this by a function, like:

`\thisismystring{BLABLABLA}`, that converts into BL{\textsc{a}}BL{\textsc{a}}BL{\textsc{a}}.

Comment: You'd have problems for all commands whose name contains a capital letter. And possibly other ones because capital letters enter sometimes in the inner syntax of TeX and in those cases they must have catcode 11 or 12.

Comment: The last one is certainly possible, either pure TeX or with the `xstring` package and its `\StrSubstitute` macro.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Contrary to my comment, the `xstring` package’s `\StrSubstitute` fails with

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand*{\replaceA}[1]{%
    \StrSubstitute{#1}{A}{\textsc{a}}%
}
```

The following solution uses a TeX macro.

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\replace}[3]{%
    \def\qrr@replace##1#2##2\@qrr@replace{##1\if\relax\detokenize{##2}\relax\else#3\qrr@replace##2\@qrr@replace\fi}%
    \qrr@replace#1#2\@qrr@replace}
\newcommand*{\replaceA}[1]{\replace{#1}{A}{\textsc{a}}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\replaceA{alAbAmA}
\replaceA{BLABLABLA}
\replaceA{not one capital a}

\replace{ALABAMA}{ABA}{\textsc{aba}}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I'll make one function for each letter. :)

Comment: @user13596 I have added a comprehensive solution that works similar to `\StrSubstitute`.

Comment: Are you sure `\StrSubstitute` fails?

Comment: @egreg Without the until-now-unknown-to-me `\expandarg`, it does for me. Or in other words: I noticed that `\StrSubstitute` expands its arguments (or does some other nasty things to it) and I abandoned the `xstring` after realizing that neither `\protect`ing nor `\noexpand`ing had worked.

Comment: The documentation of `xstring` makes it clear that with the default setting, arguments are passed through `\edef` that's not very kind to `\textsc`. With `\expandarg` only one step of expansion is performed (which is necessary if you need to pass a macro to `\replaceA`). Otherwise `\noexpandarg` is even safer.

Answer (score 3):

With `xstring` it's easy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\replaceA}[1]{%
  \begingroup\expandarg
  \StrSubstitute{#1}{A}{\textsc{a}}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\mystring}{BLABLA}

\begin{document}

\replaceA{BLABLA}

\replaceA{\mystring}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

An implementation with the `l3regex` module of LaTeX3

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,l3regex}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\replaceA}{smo}
 {
  \IfNoValueTF{#3}
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     { \repla_main:NV \l_tmpa_tl #2 }
     { \repla_main:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 } }
    \tl_use:N \l_tmpa_tl
   }
   {
    \IfBooleanTF{#1}
     { \repla_main:NV #3 #2 }
     { \repla_main:Nn #3 { #2 } }
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \repla_main:Nn #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn #1 { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { A } { \c{textsc}\cB\{a\cE\} } #1
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \repla_main:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\mystring}{BLABLA}

\begin{document}

\replaceA{BLABLA}

\replaceA*{\mystring}

\replaceA{BLABLA}[\newstring]

\show\newstring

\replaceA*{\mystring}[\newstring]

\show\newstring

\end{document}
```

If no optional argument is specified, the string obtained after replacement is immediately used, otherwise it's stored in the specified control sequence.

The *-variant allows for a macro to be passed as argument.